# visual studio 2010 error when execute step into stored procedure from server explorer on bit field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My stored procedure runs fine from sql studio as you can see from below screenshot, but when I try to step into or execute from server explorer in visual studio I get error shown for the bit field. What the hell am i doing wrong ? Right click on image and do view image for better picture. thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like visual studio can't handle 'bit'. Try to rewrite your stored procedure so @getcount is a tinyint or an integer. You could also try to write "true" instead of '1' in visual studio, with a bit of luck that could do the trick.

Comment: I have a work around. (just to use the sql studio debugger). Is this a visual studio bug ? In which case I just need to wait for visual studio 2010 sp2 ..  thanks

Comment: if the "true" failed, then it is a studio bug. Otherwise it is just a feature.

Comment: cool. Changing the 1 to true works. So VS expects a true false instead of 1 and 0. thanks